# Adverb position: 'has been constantly increasing'

Tags: adverb-position

I have the following sentence:

"The share of solar energy **has been constantly** increasing in Europe"

Grammarly tells me that this is a mistake and suggest writing:
'has constantly been increasing'

Is my version a grammatical mistake?

Comment: Have you read this? 
 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186227/adverb-order-has-largely-been-or-has-been-largely

Comment: Yes I have read this and there it is stated that both are correct. Still I wanted to get sure about this, as grammarly shows that my version is wrong

Comment: @Peter Be "*it is stated that both are correct. Still I wanted to get sure about this*"... I agree "*Both are correct*." In general, adverbs are flexible in their position in a sentence.

Comment: "The share of solar energy has (ȹ) been ȹ increasing ȹ in Europe" and  "The share of solar energy has been increasing in Europe ... ȹ" show positions where 'constantly' may be placed.